# Linux Bash SSH - Why won't my port forwarding tunnel command work?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

The commands I'm trying are:

```
ssh -vxNn -L 8080:192.168.x.xx:80 hostname@server
ssh -vxNn -L 8080:192.168.x.xx:80 hostname@server
```

Where the "x" is masked for security as is the hostname and server, but I actually am running it with numbers in there.

I'm connected remotely to a server and when I run these commands I get the following feedback/error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the syntax or is there a permission issue maybe?

Comment: 1) Those 2 commands are the same command. 2) The syntax looks fine. 3) Do you have permission to ssh to it?

Answer (score 0):

do you also get permission denied if you run?

```
ssh hostname@server
```

Can you paste the whole debug output perhaps?